# LIBVLC callbacks for video and audio playback

Tags: c#, vlc, playback, libvlc

I need to use `libvlc_video_set_callbacks()` and `libvlc_audio_set_callbacks` (or any other callbacks) to **output video and audio** in the needed box or widget.

I created the respective functions for these callbacks, but what code must be inside them for their work correctly? I know that the site **libvlc** has a description of these functions, but for me it is not enough to understand, so I need an example on **C#** (or on C++, but without using of SDL as [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_SampleCode_SDL/)), or indeed understandable description for each function, including what parameters are needed and how to use them for video and audio playback.

Very need any help!

[Ref Link](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_SampleCode_SDL/)

Comment: I am not very clear about your precise aims but to understand the use of libvlc in c# look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109639/nVLC or also http://www.helyar.net/2009/libvlc-media-player-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, you want to playback the frames and audio samples provided by libvlc using callbacks function.

First, once libvlc gives you the data via callback function, there is no way to ask it to play those in any way.

So you should push all this data into some context and use other libraries to play the video in the needed box. For the audio part only I use portaudio [[http://www.portaudio.com/]](http://www.portaudio.com/%5d) in C++ dont know much about C# though.

In the example you have SDL is the third party used to display the video provided by libvlc.

Hope it helps.